# Ecs run vs ecs deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, web-deployment, amazon-ecs

for example for a migrate task we do `ecs run` and for any long running service to deploy we do `ecs deploy`. Why so?
What is basic fundamental difference between these two. Because `ecs run` doesnt give back the status of the task ran. (it always returns a non zero status code on running the service). So we have to do polling to get the status of the deployment. So why cant we use `ecs deploy` instead of `ecs run` because ecs deploy returns the status of the deployment also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is basic fundamental difference between these two.

`aws ecs run-tusks` starts **a single task**, while `aws ecs deploy` **deploys a new task definition to a service**.

Thus the different is that a single service can run many long-running tasks. Since you are running many tasks in a service you need to have a **deployment strategy** (e.g. rolling or blue/green) for how you deploy new versions of your task definitions.

So the choice of which to use depends on your specific use cases. For ad-hoc short running jobs, a single task can be sufficient. For hosting business critical containers, a service is the right choice.